# Exception doesn't make exception for DataFrame python

Tags: python, pandas, exception

I tried to load some data from an excel file and check if some values are integers. However, I am unsuccessful and the `IsInt` method does not trigger any exceptions. Why?

In the Excel file, an integer can be saved as 5.00 as well.

```
class Load;
    def __init__(self, path="data.xls"):
        self.data = pd.read_excel(path, header=1, sheetname=0)
        self.diction = self.data.to_dict(orient='index')

    def IsInt(self, i, j):
        try:
           num = int(self.data.iat[i,j])
        except ValueError:
           print('error')

load = Load()
load.IsInt(0, 0)
```

Comment: Why not using `isinstance(self.data.iat[i, j], int)`? If `self.data.iat[i, j]` is a double (for example, 3.14) it will not throw an Exception and num will be 3.

Comment: @ArthurGouveia, It doesn't help and it is still in the first branch and therefore the error is not printed. 
To clarification: I have an excel file, where on some poisitons SHOULD be integers (number of some entities) and if the input is incorrect I want to write an error message.

Comment: Any float can converted to an int without triggering an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, `num = int(1.6)` does not cause an error. It just sets `num` to `1` by truncating the fractional part.

To check if a number is really an integer, do something like `if x == int(x): ...`. You should still catch the `TypeError` in case `x` is not a number at all.

Here is how you could apply this:

```
def IsInt(self, i, j):
    try:
       num=self.data.iat[i, j]
       if num != int(num):
          raise ValueError()
    except TypeError, ValueError:
       print('error')
```

This will print errors for string cells and cells with float values like 3.14. It will allow cells with actual ints and cells containing floats with no fractional part, like 5.0.

Step by step breakdown:

1. `int(num)` will remove any types that are not strings or numbers from consideration by raising a `TypeError`. It will also remove strings that do not represent integers with a `ValueError`.
2. `num != int(num)` eliminates any integer strings and numeric types that contain fractional parts. To trigger the same response as in #1, we manufacture our own `ValueError`.
3. The only remaining types that do not trigger an error are numerical types (`int`, `float`, `Fraction`, etc.), which do not have a fractional part.

Comment: @Arthur. I am using the fact that I already have a try catch block to avoid code duplication. This is a reasonably common algorithm

Comment: @ArthurGouveia. It is also much better to use duck typing in this case because you really can't be sure what the type of `num` is going to be up front. It could be `str`, `date`, `float`, `int`, etc. My method automatically filters out anything that doesn't behave like a number.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
class Load;
    def __init__(self, path="data.xls"):
        self.data = pd.read_excel(path, header=1, sheetname=0)
        self.diction = self.data.to_dict(orient='index')

    def IsInt(self, i, j):
        if isinstance(self.data.iat[i,j], int)
           num=self.data.iat[i,j]
        else:
           print('error')
```

Since `num` is not used inside or outside `IsInt` you can have a cleaner version of `IsInt`

```
def IsInt(self, i, j):
    if not isinstance(self.data.iat[i, j], int):
        print('error')
```

Comment: yeah, I tried really hard to do it with try/except but this is very acceptable. Thanks!
However, I slightly modified it hence the integer input can be in a form of 5.000 (for example)
`if not (self.data.iat[i, j] % 1 == 0.0):`

Comment: This does not pass integer floats.